# I cannot change the "data cannot be deleted" option within the of the Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

Although I have entered my information in the Data Safety section as indicated below, the message that data cannot be deleted does not change. Has anyone else encountered this issue, or how can I change it?

[image]

- Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?

> YES

- Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? Learn about how you should answer

> YES

- Which of the following methods of account creation does your app support? Select all that apply

> Username and password

- Add a link that users can use to request that their account and associated data is deleted

> XXX.COM/protection-of-personal-data/

Comment: How did you fix it?